# Best psychic badge

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-request

I think it would be nice to have it, considering that a good part of Stack Overflow questions demand psychic abilities.

It gets awarded to those who get at least +5 votes on questions that have -5 or less votes, and at least two more answers with -1 or less.

Comment: While psychic debugging is incredibly impressive I'm not sure an algorithm could easily detect it. After all there are many kinds of bad question

Comment: Also, I don't tend to think it's a good idea to post "psychic" answers. More often than not, they end up being noise. Better to get clarification on the question, first.

Answer (score 15):

We already have a similar badge: [Reversal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal)

Comment: And you might get one for this very question. Nice! ;)

Comment: He can't because he needs two more answers with negative votes. I don't think there will be because all users understood my question :P

Comment: @Alex: I think Sha meant the Reversal badge.

Comment: then reversal is not similar to my badge :P

Comment: @Alex: Your suggestion of the badge depending on other downvoted answers would reward abuse (there's an incentive to downvote other answers *just* to win the badge)

Answer (score 7):

We don't want to encourage people to try to answer bad questions without enough information to determine an answer.  We want questions without enough information to be closed, edited, sufficient information added, reopened, and *then* answered.

Answers that are just guessing wildly and that aren't at least reasonably confident in a solution are quite harmful on such questions.  If you guess wrong then it makes it much harder for the question to be properly edited, as it is now invalidating answers.  It also encourages people to continue to post low quality questions with little information, rather than encouraging people to provide enough information to provide a quality answer.

Comment: And if you guess right, you teach people that even awful questions will get a great answer, which is even worse IMO.

Answer (score 4):

Answering bad questions is one of the worst behaviors we have on Stack Overflow, we really shouldn't reward people for it.

This badge would perpetuate a cycle of bad questions. If users see that awful questions get answered there's no motivation to ask better questions. Worse still there's little motivation to close rather than answer, basically you lower the bar to a point where all questions get answered regardless of topic or quality and the signal to noise ratio goes down the tubes.

Comment: I completely agree. [And yet we reward it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209018/192221). Strange.

Comment: @Duncan I think the purpose of the reversal badge  is to encourage people to salvage questions. Take a bad question, edit it into a useful condition, then answer it.

Comment: Hmmm, not totally convinced. If the badge was about salvaging bad questions, it would be something like "Made an edit to a question that improved the score by 5 points or more". Instead, it seems to be about getting a great answer despite the awful question - exactly what you and I agree is questionable behaviour.